# ActiveModel::Errors when mass updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

On a single instance, validation would produce something like:

```
foo = Foo.new(price: -2)
foo.valid?
foo.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fc66e670430
 @base=#<Foo:0x00007fc6503f8658 id: nil, price: nil,
 @details={:price=>[{:error=>:greater_than_or_equal_to, :value=>-0.2e1, :count=>0}]},
 @messages={:price=>["must be greater than or equal to 0"]}>
```

Is there a rails way of obtaining the errors when using the update method?:

```
Foo.update([1, 2, 3], [{ price: 10 }, { price: -20 }, { price: 3 }])
```

Thank you!

Comment: As per https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class, `Foo.update...` should return the collection of records and then, you should be able to iterate upon it to see the errors for each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end:

```
class FooUpdateService
  attr_reader :errors

  def update(ids, values)
    self.errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(Foo.new)
    Foo.update(ids, values).select(&:invalid?).each { |invalid_foo| self.errors.merge!(invalid_foo.errors) }
  end

  private

  attr_writer :errors
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to gather errors from the [`Model.update(...)`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/update) method:

```
# first create a payload with ids and attributes
payload = { 1 => { price: 10 }, 2 => { price: -20 } }
# next update records
result = Foo.update(payload.keys, payload.values)
# the update method returns processed records
# in case of array it will return array of records
# iterate over all objects and find invalid
with_errors = result.map { |r| !r.errors.any? ? nil : r }.compact
# after compact the with_errors variable contains only invalid records.
```